# How to change the ".." in my dataframe?

Tags: r

The dataframe looks like below and I've left out some unrelevant rows and cols.

```
CountryCode rank Country GDP                
COM 182     Comoros 596

DMA 183     Dominica    480

TON 184     Tonga   472

FSM 185     Micronesia, Fed. Sts.   326

STP 186     S鉶 Tom?and Principe 263

PLW 187     Palau   228

MHL 188     Marshall Islands    182

KIR 189     Kiribati    175

TUV 190     Tuvalu  40



ASM         American Samoa  ..

ADO         Andorra ..

CYM         Cayman Islands  ..

CHI         Channel Islands ..

CUW         Cura鏰o  ..

DJI         Djibouti    

FRO         Faeroe Islands  ..

PYF         French Polynesia    ..

GRL         Greenland   ..

GUM         Guam    ..

IMY         Isle of Man ..

PRK         Korea, Dem. Rep.    ..

LBY         Libya   ..

LIE         Liechtenstein   ..

MMR         Myanmar ..
```

After I read this csv file, I want to substitude ".." for "", so I use the code:

```
df3$GDP <- as.numeric(gsub("..", "", df3$GDP))
```

It turns out that the numbers are turned to be 0, 1, 2, ... and the ".." are  turned to be NA, however , if I use

```
df3$GDP <- as.numeric(gsub(",", "", df3$GDP))
```

Then it turns out to be OK because the original numbers are still in the GDP column and the ".." has been changed to NA. I can't figure it out why this happend. Can you help me ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We need to escape  (`\\`) the `.` as it is a metacharacter (which implies any character) to get the literal meaning of the character.

```
as.numeric(gsub("\\.+", "", df3$GDP))
```

Or otherwise use `fixed = TRUE`

```
as.numeric(gsub("..", "", df3$GDP, fixed = TRUE))
```

However, the `,` is not a metacharacter so we don't need to escape